# DiscordJS Get Bot latency in slash command

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I have a problem. I want to get the bot latency but i use slash commands not the client.on("message") event. How can i do ?
Thank U

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please add to your question some code and what you tried. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just as normal, using the web socket of your <client>.

```js
<client>.ws.ping
```

The <client> means your `Client`, whatever it is set as and the ws means web socket and ping just means ping in ms.